# Should I include my master study in resume?

Tags: interviewing, resume

I am now fresh graduate (Bachelor Degree in Electronic Engineering) which completed studies in August 2016, then I enroll myself for a Master Degree in Telecommunication Engineering (part time by coursework) in September. I only attend classes on Sunday. Should I include the Master studies in my resume under Education category? or should I hide the fact that I am study master right now?
As I worry that I might get disadvantage during interview as the employer might think that I will not be able to focus in work. I hope you guys could share some information or your experience to me. Thanks

Comment: Many employers encourage part time study.   Some even pay for it.

Comment: @Paparazzi so you mean I should tell that I am now taking master course right? (Bravely)

Comment: There is little to no downside for including it.  Even better if you can explain how what you are learning will help you in the job you are trying to get.

Comment: I guess I wouldn't work for a company which encourages its employees not to study during their personal time, no matter if it's a Master's Degree, a certification, or an informal training. I'd include it in my CV, without a doubt.

Comment: @charmander thanks, your first sentence really hits the vital point. ok i will include it

Comment: Yes I would include it unless you think they might read it as once you get your Masters you will move to another company.

Comment: Please tell us about your work experience as that make a whole lot of difference.

Comment: I included it in my resume when I was working on my MS, and it helped me get my current job. Definitely include it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would include this under education on your resume with an expected graduation date:

> Masters in Telecommunication Engineering, University of Houston,
>   expected December 2017

They will be able to figure out from this that you are pursuing the degree part-time (since you are planning to work) and that you are committed to finishing it. Most employers encourage continuing professional development, including advanced degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You must include that you are pursuing your masters as a part time.

I'm also an electronics engineer.
According to me B.Tech is not sufficient for electronics stream.
So a masters becomes a kind of necessity.

It will be improve the depth of your knowledge.

Moreover you are going for the classes on weekends so that must not be affecting you while in job.

This will show your will to learn and that's what a company want.

Comment: You don't **have** to include that information, a resume is meant to sell you, to the company that is thinking about hiring you.  Being a student part time, that has no effect on your job, is your business.  Of course being a masters student is a good thing though.  It could be a masters in Underwater Basketweaving, it doesn't really matter, you don't have to include information that isn't relevant for the job your applying to

Comment: Then You are definitely going to buy a thing with an extra certification over others @Ramhound

Answer (score -1):

I would include it, definitely. It is nothing but a good thing that you consider education and training a continuing and ongoing thing.

<strike>However, I would add it not under 'education', but under extra curricular activities, or interests and hobbies. As a 'sunday only' activity I would feel it better fits here. Once you have passed of course, it should go under education, but as an interest and outside hobby, the continuation of your interest in your subject matter and your perseverance to self improve it would sit very well indeed. Also in this section there is no doubt that this is a side line of a continuing interest and will not interfere with your job or work.</strike>

Just add it to your education. Putting it in the section I originally suggested, following comments and a re-think, is actually a bit silly.

Just to say you gain nothing from leaving it off, but stand to gain a lot of credit by adding it in.

Comment: it's not a _sunday only_ activity, it's a week-long activity that requires some travel on sundays. Also, putting it in an extra curricular section might be taken as you're not serious enough about your studies, or that it's easy enough to not be listed under Education (and thus, not be taken seriously)

Comment: " I only attend classes on Sunday." So it is a sunday activity. I get what you mean though, of course, that it takes work during the week, but the time commitment is on Sunday. As for it not being serious, it was a response to the concern about putting it under education that it might seem the job was an addition to the study, not the other way around. Do people that go to church on Sunday not think their religion is serious? Your implication that you are not serious about your studies because you continue your education while working does not hold water.

Comment: @PaulD just because he only has to attend classes on Sunday, doesn't mean it's a Sunday activity. He's likely expected to be studying throughout the week to keep up with the coursework. His professor (or professors) would likely not consider this a 'sunday activity' either, as they expect their students to dedicate time throughout the week to their studies. If it was 'sunday only' activity, I don't think he would have had any reason to post here, since his employer wouldn't have any reason to believe it would interfere with his work.

Comment: I never implied what you say in the last line of your comment. The point of my argument is, since you already have an _Education_ section that's where educational activities should go. If an activity is on the CV but on a section separate to _Education_, it's probably not an educational activity.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. Point taken.